# monitor and send mail if file is not present or changed

Tags: file-management, monitoring

I have a system that zips and copy the SQL-backup to a central FTP-server that I manage. Every client has its own folder wich contains the backups for the last 7 days.

Now I need a system that monitors those folders and let me know if a certain backup is missing (= last backup > 24 hours or doesn't exist).

I've been searching on the internet, but all I can find are tools that send mails if a file or directory changes, I want the opposite in certain point of view.

I use Filezilla Server, but found no option to mail from there. The server is running Windows.

Any tips?